# Linkedin REST API: Update OAuth2.0 Access token using php from a CRON job?

Tags: php, rest, cron, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have an application that needs to be able to refresh the oauth2.0 access token every 59 days through a cron job. I don't want to have the user perform the authenticate again on the front end, I just want this to happen on the backend using a cron. Is this even possible? The main problem with the cron is that to get another valid oauth2.0 access token there needs to be a redirect. Does this redirect send information back to the cron for execution?

Overall, at a high level I only want the user to grant permissions once for my app to get a valid oauth2.0 access token. I will store this in my database and after 59 days and I will execute a cron job to retrieve another one (without the user ever having to do anything). Therefore the app works seamlessly and the user will never have to be authenticated again.

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a cron job for this. Once you have the initial access token (you might also have a refresh token at that time) you can refresh that anytime, at the same time your app initiates a connection to the external service. So right before you attempt to read or write data from the external service, refresh the token first, then proceed with the API requests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses Matt.  I don't understand what you mean by "you can refresh that at anytime".  Here is how I am getting the first access token http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication.  The docs state that this is the only workflow for using the REST API to get a valid oauth2.0 access token, as well refreshing one.  And if right before I attempt to make an api my oauth2.0 access token has expired then I wouldn't be able to do any thing.  Basically I need a way to refresh this token every 59 days without the end user having to grant permissions again.

Comment: I meant you can refresh that at anytime within the 60 day window (to gain another 60 days). Sorry for the confusion. It sounds like you want to have the access token refreshed even if the user has not connected to LI through your application in over 60 days? I don't have an answer then because the whole point of tokens expiring is to **not** give any one app lifetime access to a user's data. If the user truly hasn't utilized your app in over 60 days, they *should* have to reauthorize. A cron can't authorize an app via OAuth - that has to be done by the user themselves.

Comment: Also, by refreshing the token before making an api call does that mean I have to get authorization code again through a redirect to get this new refreshed access token?  I need a way to get a refreshed access token without the redirect.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible as long as it's within the 60 day window. The only time the user has to manually authorize the app (through the redirect) is after 60 days.

Comment: Ok I understand that I can get another access token if I currently have one, but for the new OAuth2.0 access token the only way to refresh it is to use the redirect.  Here are the docs for refreshing an oauth1.0 access token http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token.  There is a thread on the dev forms that states you have to go through the same auth flow to refresh the OAuth2.0 access token (this involves a redirect) http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/refresh-accesstoken-using-url.